# Adding to a Collection (List) via WebApi POST

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add favourites to a collection - `List<Attraction>` whenever a user clicks on a link for the desired `Attraction`.

My Api Controller is as follows:

```
public class FavouritesController : ApiController
{
    private List<Attraction> _favourites;

    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public FavouritesController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Attraction> Get()
    {
        return _favourites;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(int id)
    {
        if (_favourites == null)
        {
            _favourites = new List<Attraction>();
        }

        var attraction = _repo.FindAttractionById(id);

        if (attraction == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _favourites.Add(attraction);

        return Ok();
    }
```

And this is my AngularJS Service:

```
function addToFavourites(id) {
    $http.post("/api/v1/favourites/" + id)
        .success(function(response) {
           //Success
        })
```

Then in the Angular controller for page:

```
$scope.addToFavourites = function() {
    dataService.addToFavourites(this.attraction.id);
    $scope.Favourites = dataService.getFavourites();
}
```

It works when I set breakpoint - but only adds one item to the collection - so if I click on the first item it adds the first item, but then if click on the second item it adds second item, but does not keep the first.

If I do a `Get` request in browser to `localhost:xxxx/api/v1/favourites` it just says `null` in window. How can I fix this and ensure state of the collection remains consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, HTTP is state less. It means every request is a new request, and `List<Attraction> _favourites` will always be null in your code.

If you want to persist the data, you want to keep it in persistent storage like database.

If you just want to test the API *for the sake of testing*, you can make  **static** -

```
private static List<Attraction> _favourites;
```

Comment: Thanks, its just for testing at moment - will add to Db as next task.